Combine CodeMeter license management with SQL Server Always Encrypted
I would like to activate Always Encrypted into my SQL Server database to protect a few sensible columns and access it from an external application.
As per my understanding, I have to:

Configure Always Encrypted on the database (using both CEK and CMK keys)
Develop my client using a MS library to connect to such database with encrypted columns. In official docs, I found such library named the "driver"
From within my client application, I have to provide CMK key to the driver.

Takeout is that I need to handle CMK on my client application.
My CMK will be an encryption key that is stored into Wibu CodeMeter, as a secret in a license, and it does not allow direct extraction of the key from the license. Instead it provides an API to encrypt/decrypt data specifying in what license the key is stored into.
So far seems like there is no way to combine the two technologies, as I cannot get a hold of the key from CodeMeter to pass it over to the driver library. This makes me formulate those questions:

Why Wibu CodeMeter, and I believe other encryption keys management, prevents key extraction?

I guess that we don't want the encryption key to be clear in memory when the process is running, as to prevent to spot the key while debugging, for example.


If in a secure environment we don't want the keys to circulate clear in memory, how could possibly Always Encrypted pretend to receive a key as input?

Given that I am no security expert, I suppose either I missed something or this combination is just not possible and what I am trying to do makes no sense at all from an architectural standpoint.

My understanding was wrong. To connect to a SQL Server with Always Encrypted enabled, an ODBC URL with proper parameters is sufficient, given that the SQL Server ODBC driver is installed in the client application.
An example of connection string:
jdbc:sqlserver://host\dbname;integratedSecurity=true;encrypt=true;database=MyDB;trustServerCertificate=true;columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled
The setting columnEncryptionSetting=Enabled is the one required to connect to an instance with Always Encrypted on.
Only Azure Key Store and Windows Credential Store are supported out of the box; is possible to connect to other stores by implementing a connector using dedicated APIs: more details here on official MS docs.
